# Prove the approximate identity from the unitization

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra without unit, $A^+$ is a unitization
 of $A$, treat $A$ in the $A^+$, if $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ converge （or monotonous converge） to $1$ in $A^+$, does $\{x_n\}$ must be the approximate identity in $A$?

If yes，let a is a strictly positive element in $A$, $a^{1/n}$ is approximate identity in $A$, we can prove it from above way ($\{1,a\}$ generates a subalgebra isomorphism with $C(K)$ and $a^{1/n}$ converge to $1$ in $C(K)$), but some books prove it with some long technology related the representation, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The norm in $A^+$ is the same as in $A$. So if your sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $1$, this means that $1\in A$, since $A$ is complete (as it sits as a closed ideal in $A^+$).

To think about this stuff it is often useful to think of $C_0(\mathbb R)$ as your prototype of non-unital C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks. Does any simple proof(without use the representation)  for a$^1$$^/$$^n$ is an approximate identity in the above question?

Comment: I don't really know. In the canonical examples of non-unital C$^*$-algebras, namely $C_0(X)$ and $K(H)$, I can do it; but in both cases I  need to explicitly use what the elements look like. So I wouldn't know how to do it in an arbitrary non-unital $A$.